# If $\{x_n\}_n$ is a totally bounded set, does the sequence $(x_n)$ converges?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $x_n$ be a sequence that converges to zero in the weak topology. Assuming that the set $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots \}$ is totally bounded, does the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to zero in norm?

The fact that $x_n$ converges to zero in the weak topology implies that if $(x_n)$ converges in $X$, then it must converges to zero. So it is sufficient  to show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. If not, exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $n$, exists $l_n, m_n \geq n$ such that
$$ \| x_{l_n} - x_{m_n} \| < \epsilon. $$
By the other side, exists $n_{1}, \dots, n_{k}$ such that
$$ \{x_n\}_n \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^k B(x_{n_j}, \epsilon). $$

I'm not so sure how to get a contradiction here.

Help?

Comment: Hint: If the sequence does not converge to zero, there is a subsequence which has norm bounded below by some $\epsilon >0$. What can you say about this subsequence?

Comment: @PhoemueX It cannot have any convergent subsequence.

Comment: Try to use Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem...

Comment: Since $X$ is a complete normed space, the sequence has limit points. Assume $x$ is such a limit point. _A fortiori_ $\varphi(x) = \lim \varphi(x_n) = 0$ for every continuous linear form $\varphi.$ By virtue of Banach-Hanh extension theorem, $x = 0.$ Thus, the sequence $(x_n),$ which is totally bounded, has one limit point. _A fortiori_ it converges to that limit point.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that any subsequence of $\{x_n\}_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$ in norm, so fix a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_k$ of $\{x_n\}_n$. $\{x_{n_k}\}_k$ lies in the set $\overline{\text{span}\{x_n :n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$ which is norm-compact because it is totally bounded and closed, hence $\{x_{n_k}\}_k$ has a subsequence, say $\{x_{n_{k_c}}\}_c$ which converges to an $x\in X$ in norm. Since $\{x_{n_{k_c}}\}_c$ is known to converge weakly to $0$ we must have $x=0$ so we are done.